wkhtmltopdf not working in Sylius project
First of all, i installed Sylius using the following command :
git clone git@github.com:Sylius/Sylius-Standard.git sylius && cd sylius && make init

I tried to add the wkhtmltopdf binary file to the Sylius Docker container following this tutorial: https://blog.bitexpert.de/blog/sylius_docker_alpine_wkhtmltopdf
I modified the existing compose.override.yml as follows:
php:
    build: ./Docker/
    user: ${DOCKER_USER:-1000:1000}

And for the Dockerfile, I did the following instructions :
FROM surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.16.2-0.12.6-full as wkhtmltopdf

FROM ghcr.io/sylius/sylius-php:8.2-fixuid-xdebug-alpine AS base

USER root
# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        acl \
        file \
        gettext \
        unzip \
        libstdc++ \
        libx11 \
        libxrender \
        libxext \
        libssl3 \
        openssl \
        ca-certificates \
        fontconfig \
        freetype \
        ttf-droid \
        ttf-freefont \
        ttf-liberation \
    ;

RUN ln -s /lib/libssl.so.1.1.1 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1 && \
    ln -s /lib/libcrypto.so.1.1.1 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1

# Copy needed wkhtmltopdf files from wkhtmltopdf image
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltoimage /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin/libwkhtmltox* /usr/local/bin/

However, when I ran the docker-compose build, I couldn't find the wkhtmltopdf file in /usr/local/bin/.

Are you sure your problem is in any way related to Symfony or Sylius? If you cannot even find the binaries at the expected place, I would assume that this is a problem of your Dockerfile?

may be i tag it also with docker & dockerfile

Finally, I found a solution to my problem: there needs to be consistency between the versions of surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf and ghcr.io/sylius/sylius-php
So, Here's the Dockerfile code that works well for me :
FROM surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.20.0-0.12.6-full as wkhtmltopdf

FROM ghcr.io/sylius/sylius-php:8.2-fixuid-xdebug-alpine AS sylius_php

USER root
# install wkhtmltopdf runtime dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libstdc++ \
    libx11 \
    libxrender \
    libxext \
    libssl3 \
    ca-certificates \
    fontconfig \
    freetype \
    ttf-droid \
    ttf-freefont \
    ttf-liberation

# Copy needed wkhtmltopdf files from wkhtmltopdf image
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltoimage /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin/libwkhtmltox* /usr/local/bin/


Good point! I don't use sylius but php:8.3-fpm-alpine3.20 image and I had the same issue. With a matching version, it is now working!
